# Django: Get field attribute DateTime values

Tags: python, django, datetime, attributes

I am trying to iterate over a model's attributes, getting both the verbose name and value for each attribute.  I have no problem for character/numerical values, but I am struggling with DateTime values.  Of course I can do this manually, but some of my models have dozens of attributes (only a few of which are DateTimes), so it would be nice if I could figure out how to do this programatically.

My code currently (with the 'History' Model class):

```
def get_fields(self):
    return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in History._meta.fields]
```

In the case of a DateTime, of course this outputs a string, such as: `2011-06-16T04:00:00+00:00`

Suggestions on pulling out DateTime values?  Apologies if this is a very basic question -- I have been using Django for about a year, but am more recently trying to tackle area's I am unfamiliar with.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use strftime() on datetime objects to specify how the string representation should be formatted, but you probably have to override the value_to_string() method in the datetimefield if you want to iterate over all fields in a uniform way.

See python doc of datetime.strftime() here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm OK with using strftime() to format datetime objects, just not sure how to deal with it in this case when I am trying to iterate over the fields (most of which are characters/numbers).